# Provide parameters to EF Core Scaffold-DBContext on runtime/in code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

In our project we frequently have to reimport the database defintions for a number of different databases. Before we switched to Entity Framework Core 3.1 we used edmx generators.

Via the Scaffold-DbContext command in the package manager console we can import the database models, but need to manually provide the connection string and all the other database specific parameters by hand.

1. Is there a way to just call "Scaffold-DbContext" without any parameters and EF Core then loads the required parameters from a project specific config or something similar?
2. Otherwise is there an easy way to call Scaffold-DbContext from a C# Application? My idea being that I would write a small console app that updates the models by calling the Scaffold-DbContext command with the project specfic parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this one https://github.com/jdtcn/RuntimeEfCore

Comment: Why not use [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) cli? Crate a script with required parameters and double-click when you need.

Comment: Hi, there is a way to run ef commands into cmd or ps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet, an so they can be easely executed throught console app or some kind of service or so

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools?